# Shortcut to clear Java's "temporary internet files"

Tags: java, temporary-internet-files

At work, we regularly need to use the Java Control Panel to clear Java's *Temporary Internet Files* while testing legacy Java applications. Since we frequently need to clear the Java Cache, I want to create a shortcut for clearing the cache on Windows.

*[A similar question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/904144/3357935)* discussed how to programmatically clear Java's temporary internet files, but this isn't much help, as I do not have developer access to make code modifications.

**How can I create a shortcut for clearing Java's temporary internet files?**

[image: Java's temporary internet files]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How can I create a shortcut for clearing Java's temporary internet files?

Windows 7  or later batch file:

```
for /D %%a in (*.*) do DEL /F /S /Q "%%a\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\*.*"
for /D %%a in (*.*) do FOR /D %%b IN ("%%a\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\*.*") DO RMDIR /S /Q "%%b"
```

Windows XP batch file:

```
for /D %%a in (*.*) do DEL /F /S /Q %%a\Application Data\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\*.*"
for /D %%a in (*.*) do FOR /D %%b IN (%%a\Application Data\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\*.*) DO RMDIR /S /Q "%%b
```

Source [Cleanup Windows & Java Temporary Files using a Batch Script](https://www.samontech.com/cleanup-windows-temporary-files-batch-script/)